# redesigning backbone page and handling events

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am still kind of new to backbone and I have a question.  I am currently working on a previously created backbone view.  This view is responsible for all the saving within the application.  The class is becoming exceedingly large and I wanted to split out some of the events/methods/function to their own "sub class", if that is possible.  For example, I have a group of events and functions that are responsible for a specific task.  I would like to move those event and functions to their own js page, in a sub folder.  The problem is that the events are being called.  Here is a general overview of how the class is setup:

> var myClass= myClassBaseClass.extend({
>
> ```
> events: {
>      .... all my events here,
>     'click .eventOneButton': 'eventOne',
> },
> initialize: function (options) {
>      //initialize stuff here
> },
>     postRender: function (renderOptions) {
>       //post render here
> },
> preRender: function (renderOptions, html) {
>     return html;
> },   template: function (renderOptions) {    //template stuff       },
> //...etc.
> ```
>
> //my events
>
> //eventOne was here, now its moved to its own file
>
> });

My new file is in a subfolder, and looks like this:

> var myClassSubClass= myClass.extend({
>
> ```
> eventOne: function(e){
>   //event stuff here   
> }
> ```
>
> });

So, is what am I doing wrong?  Why wont the event get caught in the second file?

thanks
jason

Comment: Bind the event in the subview, and don't forget to call `delegateEvents`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I created an events section in my sub class, but how do I call delegateEvents?  I don't think I've used this before.